# Dummy/Temporary data to build a dynamic UI

Tags: android, json, architecture, dummy-data

I'm entry level developer and i got  to build some parts of an app. The backend of the app isn't ready yet, so i need some kind of dummy data to work with since i need to build ListViews etc with the data from backed.The way i'll get the data is throught calls that return JSON. Should i build some JSON myself to test it? I try to avoid implementing a logic that will be entirely changed once the real data are ready, because i dont know the structure of the real data.

Any sources that can help me or suggestion? Is there a specific or common way to deal on those situations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Based On UI you design json data and try....

Comment: ok so that's a way to go? Dont get me wrong, i dont doubt. I just want to know the best way to go :D

Comment: Based On UI you have to predict what are the data required from the server. Just add dummy data in Array for testing later you can change it.

Comment: Yeah i already made the json from Mockaroo based on what my real data will probably look like, and updated them on Myjson to imitate reall HTTP calls. Thanks a lot